# .NET TLS set certificate verify signature algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

I am connecting with a https protected by an extra certificate check (via a smart card).

My problem is that when I call the endpoint from .NET/C# it throws "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.", calling it from Chrome works fine. I managed to trace the problem with Wireshark and the culprit is when the client exchanges the algorithm for Certificate Verify.

Broken:

[image: Broken]

Working:

[image: Working]

My code:

```
public string GetToken()
    {
        var req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(this.AuthenticationUrl);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.ClientCertificates.Add(this.Certificate);

        var resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (var respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        using (var respReader = new StreamReader(respStream))
        {
            string xml = respReader.ReadToEnd();

            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var message = doc.FirstNode as XElement;
            var content = message.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "contents");
            this.Token = content.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "accessToken").Attribute("value").Value;
            string expires = content.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.LocalName == "expiresOn").Attribute("value").Value;
            this.TokenExpiresOn = DateTime.Parse(expires);

            return this.Token;
        }
    }
```

this.Certificate is a valid X509Certificate2 from a smart card.

It seems that .NET somehow sets rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 and the server can't handle it?

How can I force .NET/C# to use rsa_pkcs1_sha256?